# Why does ORM `hasDataChanges()` behave incorrectly?

Tags: magento-1.8, model

I'm confused by the way Magento's ORM behaves when editing/saving an object; see the example below:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('vendor/model')
    ->setData(array(
        'name'        => 'Test,
        'description' => 'Info',
    ))
    ->save();
```

I now have a new record in the table, however this is where i'm confused.

```
$model = Mage::getModel('vendor/model')->load(1);
$model->setName('Test');  // THIS IS THE SAME
$model->setDescription('Info'); // THIS IS THE SAME

var_dump($model->hasDataChanges()); // returns true! (i expect false)
var_dump(($model->getData() !== $model->getOrigData())) // returns false (expected)
```

Surely the latter is how Magento should behave? Unless i'm missing something.

Comment: As David points out, this is a programmatic intent (opinion) in the framework. Not sure if this is to reduce overhead of always checking if being-set value is == to current value, but that's simply the way it's written.

Comment: @benmarks Hmm okay. The way that I looked at it was one could simply parse an array of data to `setData` then save, but this would query the database unnecessarily which surely it's more efficient for php to condition whether changes exist. Either way, I was only curious since I used the latter example above anyway, understanding I suppose.

Comment: You've asked a pertinent question here, one I've heard it many times in the Fundamentals class. I'm not aware of / smart enough to know the basis for this ORM opinion. FYI you can compare ORM object's `_origData` array `_data`, though for the purpose of write logic  `_data` may contain extraneous members which are not persisted (i.e. no corresponding attribute or column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the `setData` function it appears that has data changes is always set to true even if technically the data has not changes.

This can be seen in `Varien_Object function setData`

```
public function setData($key, $value=null)
{
    $this->_hasDataChanges = true;
    if(is_array($key)) {
        $this->_data = $key;
        $this->_addFullNames();
    } else {
        $this->_data[$key] = $value;
        if (isset($this->_syncFieldsMap[$key])) {
            $fullFieldName = $this->_syncFieldsMap[$key];
            $this->_data[$fullFieldName] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Didn't you mean to say it's always true only for objects that have had their setData method called? Or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times, I'm using the following code to check if a model changed:

```
$changed = $model->__toArray(array_keys($model->getOrigData())) != $model->getOrigData();
```

However, you'll need something else if you're going to check the product/category model after saving (for example from admin panel) or any other complex model. The problem there is that many values and types are different in `$model->getData()` vs `$model->getOrigData()`.

Both product and category model have the `updated_at` field already updated. Product has also the `stock_item` object. Category has the `image` field in `getOrigData()` as type string and in `getData()` after save as array.